# Fourier dimension of sets of positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ with positive Lebesgue measure. My question is whether there exists a probability measure $\mu$ supported on $K$ such that $\hat{\mu}(\xi)$, the [Fourier-Stieltjes transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Fourier.E2.80.93Stieltjes_transform) of $\mu$, has decay $O(|\xi|^{-1})$?

Note that when $K=[0,1]$, we can simply take $\mu=\chi_{[0,1]}dt$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149660/rate-of-fourier-decay-of-indicator-functions). Generally, if $K$ contains an interior point, then by the same token such a probability measure trivially exists. But things become unclear to me when $K$ is a general set.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "$K$ contains an interior point" because obviously $[0,1]$ does contain more than one interior point!

Comment: @Mercy Your statement isn't true, the Cantor set is a counterexample. There exist even variants of the Cantor set with positive Lebesgue measure, take the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set for example.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel You're right! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the case when $K$ is a fat Cantor?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: I haven't tried. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe with Lebesgue decomposition measure, we have to look at measure written as a sum of an absolutely continuous measure (with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda$) and a singular measure (wrt $\lambda$), the discrete part won't help. I will try to do the computation in the case of a fat Cantor.